# I want to make my frame close when the X(close button) is clicked

Tags: java, awt, frame, netbeans-7

I have a small template that ive built for the purpose of implementing an applet through a simple java application via netbeans 7.1 (as in not using Javacard, Netbeans Platform etc ..just a simple java application with applet initialized when application runs)

I have managed to make it invoke the applet when i press the run button in netbeans and i ahve functionality inside the applet but, i cant seem to get it to close and i have a horrible feeling people are gonna tell me to have used jFrame and implement the EXIT_ON_CLOSE method.

This is NOT something I would like to know how to do , my mission is to implement it using Frames != jFrames.
I hope someone can help as its bugged me for a bit now and i have to get on with Java assignment that involves its use.

Enclosed is the code/classes for A: the appletframe and B:the applet

```
    * 1.4   Write an applet to display a line of text. 
    * The text should then change its font size and style (bold, italic, underline) 
    * depending on where the mouse is clicked on the screen.
    */
   package appletframe;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.applet.Applet;

  /**
  * @author MuthaLoad aka Gruffy2012
  */

  import java.awt.*;

  public class AppletFrame extends Applet{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

/*construct needs object instances*/
MrApplet mrApplet = new MrApplet(); // create instance/obj of MrApplet 
Frame myFrame = new Frame("Applet"); // create frame "title optional"
//setDefaultCloseOperation(myFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);(jFrame- not wanted)

/* add applet to the frame*/
//myFrame.addWindowListener();
myFrame.add(mrApplet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
myFrame.setBounds(10,10,500,500);
myFrame.setVisible(true); // step to make frame visible

/*initialize instance of mrApplet*/
mrApplet.init();
} // end main
} // end class
```

B: applet

```
   package appletframe;

import java.awt.*; //for buttons
import java.awt.event.*; //for events
import java.applet.*; //main applet api`s
import java.awt.Graphics; //graphics

public class MrApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Button btnClick;
String msg = "";

public void init() 
{
    // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
    setSize(500, 500);
    Button btnClick = new Button("Press Me ");
    btnClick.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnClick);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    msg = "Yay, the button works";
            repaint();
}     
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 30)); //new font obj, font , font style, font size
    g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0)); //new color obj, r,g,b
    g.drawString(msg, 40, 80); 

}  
// TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods
}
```

Once again thanks for reading, and to clarify any confusions..
I am looking for a pointer as to the solution of closing my applet and frame window upon exit , without reimplementing it all using jFrame, though i know this would be easier in the first instance.
Thankyou and as always, indebted to all your advice.
gruffy321

Comment: `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is a constant, not a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this line at the end of ApplicationFrame class.

```
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

You want to do it with Frame not with JFrame, then you have to add the **WindowListener** event to the frame and have to override **windowClosing()** method.

```
myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
   System.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, now thanks for the super quuick response but like i stated , i simply do not want a jframe option (I know the API comes with simplifed access to very simple functions that have to be implemented manually using the frame (notjFrame)API). Thankyou anyway Chandra for bing so super quick

Comment: amazing thanks for super duper quick response again chandra, i wil go off and try this out now, cheers bud.. Gruffy

Comment: RE, YOUR EDITED RESPONSE>>>>>Well i have just tried and cant work out where the ")" should go, i have added it and moved it around but to no avail, also tried adding and extra "}" to close it but hasnt worked either, I SEEM TO BE MISSING SOMETHING HERE HUH.

Comment: Missing a  closing curly closing bracket just fyi